# Merge [concat] and [concatenation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

I think the tags [concat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concat) and [concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/concatenation) are about the same concept. The wikis are quite similar too. I think these tags should be merged.

The second tag looks more popular; I would make the first one a synonym.

Comment: You should decide whether you want to request a one-time retag (merging the tags) or a synonym.

Comment: @Deduplicator I think it is the best to retag and make synonym.

Comment: @Deduplicator what would need to happen for this to actually be implemented? Would you happen to know?

Comment: @Seth Someone must suggest the synonym on the tags info-page, and then enough people must approve it. The sticking point is the answers-only score of 5 required. Alternatively, a mod can do it.